# Lucene in web page using PHP

Tags: java, php, html, lucene

I am new to Lucene. I have indexed data. 
By command line I am able to run query through Lucene. 
Now, I want the same to be done through dynamic Web Page. 
I i/p to page will be a text file as it is through command line.

thanks, 
Ravi

Comment: What are you asking? How much have you done? Are you using Zend and Lucene?

Comment: I have implemented search n working well on cmd line. Now I want same to be run through exec command in php. I am getting error:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/analysis/Analyzer Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Could not find the main class:search.Program will exit.

Comment: I have created jar file and it is working now.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is [solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/). Solr is a popular, fast open source search platform from the Apache Lucene project.
Solr uses the Lucene Java search library at its core for full-text indexing and search.
It allows you easily to get JSON or XML results over HTTP.
There is also a HTML administration interface.

You only need a servlet container such as Tomcat.

Comment: +1 Solr.  As the OP mentions PHP in the tags, I'll also suggest the Solr PHP Client as a good PHP library to interact with Solr (http://code.google.com/p/solr-php-client/) and one which I've contributed some code to.

Comment: Solr also comes with Jetty set up if you don't want to run Tomcat; but Tomcat's probably a better choice.

Comment: I don't want to change anything. Is it possible without Solr or any thing else ?